# Add new element to SVG in Angular

Tags: angular, svg

I am trying to add a new element to an SVG in Angular after I retrieve some data from the database but the 2 methods I tried don't seem to work.

I tried to use *ngFor in html

```
              <svg version="1.1" id="room" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                    viewBox="0 0 953.7 792.9" style="enable-background:new 
0 0 953.7 792.9;" xml:space="preserve">
              <style type="text/css">
                    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#3D3D3D;stroke-width:7;stroke- 
miterlimit:10;}
                    .st1{fill:#55BEFF;}
              </style>
              <g>
                    <rect *ngFor="let zone of spaceData" [attr.id]=zone.id 
[attr.x]=zone.x [attr.y]=zone.y [attr.class]=zone.class 
[attr.width]=zone.width [attr.height]=zone.height />
              </g>
              </svg>
```

and also to build it during init

```
var svgEle = document.getElementById('room');
  this.spaceData.forEach(element => {
    var rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 
'rect');
    rect.setAttribute('id', element.id);
    rect.setAttribute('x', element.x);
    rect.setAttribute('y', element.y);
    rect.setAttribute('class', element.class);
    rect.setAttribute('width', element.width);
    rect.setAttribute('height', element.height);
    svgEle.append(rect);

  });
```

But none of them seem to work. If I inspect the element the rectangles are present in the svg but they are not visible.

Comment: Are all the attributes as expected? Especially are the coordinates within the viewBox of the SVG? Do the rects have a visible stroke or fill? And can you check if the `namespaceURI` DOM property is correct – even though your code looks like it should be? Did you try different browsers to rule out that it's a browser bug?

Comment: I made it work. The SVG was in a div using FlexLayout and for some reason it didn't show up while there. My mistake:)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try out the [ngx-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-svg) library. It allows creating SVG containers and different type of svg elements easily. You can check `svg-rect`, which contains all necessary elements which you have listed.

The only change you would have to do is change the element.class to element.classes array (convert string to array of strings, thus allowing to append multiple classes to the element).

Example code, which you could use in HTML with this library, which would create the container and automatically assign the elements -

```
<svg-container containerId="rectangulars">
  <svg-rect *ngFor="let element of spaceData" [height]="element.height" [width]="element.width" [classes]="element.classes" [x]="element.x" [y]="element.y"></svg-rect>
</svg-container>
```

It has other elements as well, if you need anything else, for example, `svg-circle`, `svg-polygon`, `svg-line`, e.t.c.